# iOS storyboard - container with several sub views

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am rebuilding a iPhone application using storyboard and i can not find any way to create a custom tab control in a single view. What I would like to do is create a container like element in the storyboard, which can have several views (for instance Tab 1 content, Tab 2 content,..). And then decide in code which view to show. It is very similar to the Tab View Control but in a subview. Is this even possible or do i have to do it programmatically?  Or does any one know a way that could simplify the process (so that the tab content would be done in storyboard and linked in code)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a container view as a subview of your main view. It will automatically have a view controller connected to it with an embed segue. You can delete the default controller you get, drag out a tab bar controller, and connect it to the container view with an embed segue. I think this should give you what you want.

Comment: that does exactly what i want but the problem is that it also adds the task bar items which i do not want. And cant figure any way to remove/hide them.

Comment: @blejzz, you can use self.tabBar.hidden = YES (from a subclassed tab bar controller) to hide the tab bar.